# Python 3.x Ten green bottles = fix plurals and capitalization

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi guys im working on my assigemnt ten green bottles but every fine until the last verse which requires there to be "one green bottle" not "one green bottles" and also i how would i use the .capitalize()

```
def main():
    numbers = [
    'no',
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four',
    'Five',
    'Six',
    'Seven',
    'Eight',
    'Nine',
    'Ten', ]
text_one = 'green bottles\nHanging on the wall'
text_two = "\nAnd if one green bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be"
text_three =' \n'
# Each iteration of this loop prints one verse of the song

for i in range(10, 0, -1):         
    file=open('ten.txt', 'a')
    file.write(numbers[i]+' ')
    file.write(text_one+'\n')
    file.write(numbers[i]+' ')
    file.write(text_one+' ')
    file.write(text_two+' ')
    file.write(numbers[i-1]+' ')
    file.write(text_one+'\n')
    file.write('\n')
    file.close()

  if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: cant post the output its too long by 1024 chars

Comment: You could conditionally add the 's' on for all the times you have more than 1 bottle (although that isn't that efficient), or cut off the 's' in the cases where there is only 1 bottle (probably more efficient, but harder to do). It would be ugly, but you could also define a function where you pass a number and a String representing a word, and if the number is greater than 1, it adds a 's' to the end. And please elaborate on what problems you're having with `capitalize()`; it's a fairly straight forward function.

Comment: thank you 
about the capitalize function how do i use it exactly
with the cutting off of a s in the string how would you do this
sorry im new
just a bit confusing as this has to be written to a textfile

Comment: I can't remember if capitalize "mutates" the string, or returns a new one, but it just changes the first letter to a capital (look it up in the Python docs. Python has very good documentation). And for the latter question, look up slicing. You'll want to slice the string from the beginning, to the second last character.

Comment: Np. Have this a read over: https://docs.python.org/2/library/Strings html Should answer both questions.

Comment: opps im getting a 404 error :(

Comment: Oops, if you look at the link, the ".html" got cut off the end. Alternatively, (and this is good advice for any problem in any language), Google "Python capaitalize()". Any time I'm having a problem, just do a search with the language name first, and then whatever you want to know. Helps me 99% of the time.

Comment: could you give a hint please im having trying the ide is recognizing it as its fine but no changes have been made

Comment: Are you assigning the result of `capitalize`? It returns a capitalized copy of the string it doesn't change the original. e.g. `st.capitalize()` is wrong `st2=st.capitalize()` is right. Docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)

Comment: is this for python 3.x ?

Comment: Yes. The function is the same for 2.x and 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you closer:

```
numbers = ['Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One', 'no']
# variable to add s when needed
plural = "s"

# loop to all but last elements starting at Ten
for i, n in enumerate(numbers[:-1]):
    # if n is One we we don't need s
    if i > 8:
        plural = ""
    # get next element for second part of string
    nxt = numbers[i+1]
    text_one = '{w} green bottle{pl}\nHanging on the wall'.format(w=n, pl=plural)
    # if the next element is One we also need don't need s for text_two
    if nxt == "One":
        plural  = ""
    text_two = "And if one green bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be {nxt} green bottle{pl}"\
        .format(nxt=nxt.lower(),pl=plural)
    print(text_one+text_two+' hanging on the wall\n')
```

You need to add an `s` to `bottle` based on where you are in your list. It also matters what the next element is as when n is Two we need `bottles` and `bottle`.

To write to a file just replace print with write:

```
numbers = ['Ten', 'Nine', 'Eight', 'Seven', 'Six', 'Five', 'Four', 'Three', 'Two', 'One', 'no']
plural = "s"

with open("out.txt","w") as f:
    for i, n in enumerate(numbers[:-1]):
        if i > 8:
            plural = ""
        nxt = numbers[i+1]
        text_one = '{w} green bottle{pl}\nHanging on the wall'.format(w=n, pl=plural)
        if nxt == "One":
            plural = ""
        text_two = "And if one green bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be {nxt} green bottle{pl}"\
        .format(nxt=nxt.lower(),pl=plural)
        f.write(text_one+text_two+' hanging on the wall\n\n')
```

Comment: thank mate but im looking for a solution for my code and also it needs to be written to a text file
but thanks mate i appreciate it :)

Comment: sorry if i sound rude :(

Comment: @Gilgamesh, all you have to do is change the prints into write

Comment: True. @Gilgamesh You have the meat of the solution here. You already know how to write a file, so there shouldn't be an issue converting it.

Comment: thanks but could you edit the code so it outputs this http://www.ica30111.brambling.cdu.edu.au/pythonsite/support/TenGreenBottles.txt and everything will be complete please and thank you!

Comment: ive very much appricate it :) if its not to much trouble

Comment: Just add another newline char at the end of the string. Added it to the second part of the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's another nasty untidy way of doing it. Making minimal changes to your existing code.

Basically it allows the pluralising `s` to be optional in the string.

```
text_one = 'green bottle%s\nHanging on the wall'
```

The `%s` acts as a placeholder for the `s`, which must be filled in later when you know which iteration you are in using something like

```
f.write(text1 % 's')
```

To include the `s` or

```
f.write(text1 % '')
```

To not include the `s`.

**Full Code:**

```
def main():
    numbers = [
    'no',
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three',
    'Four',
    'Five',
    'Six',
    'Seven',
    'Eight',
    'Nine',
    'Ten']
    text_one = 'green bottle%s\nHanging on the wall'
    text_two = "\nAnd if one green bottle\nShould accidentally fall\nThere'll be"
    text_three =' \n'
    # Each iteration of this loop prints one verse of the song

    with open('ten.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(10, 0, -1):         

            f.write(numbers[i]+' ')
            if i == 1:
                f.write(text_one % '' +'\n')
            else:
                f.write(text_one % 's'+'\n')

            f.write(numbers[i]+' ')
            if i == 1:
                f.write(text_one % '' +'\n')
            else:
                f.write(text_one % 's'+'\n')
            f.write(text_two+' ')
            f.write(numbers[i-1]+' ')
            if (i - 1) == 1:
                f.write(text_one % '' +'\n')
            else:
                f.write(text_one % 's'+'\n')
            f.write('\n\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code is not very maintainable, but it should demonstrate the technique.